# Building Wix 3.0 upgrade and patch

Tags: wix, upgrade, patch, wix3

1)What are the best practices of building, patches?

2)Is it possible to build patch between major upgrade(Product code is changed) build?

3)How  to ship content(static files) update for a product
We tried to do this through patch but is was taking lot of time to update just 200 files, basically our requirement is that we want to ship periodic content update to user after he has install the product.

Answer (score 1):

The WiX documentation has information about creating patches. I highly recommend using the WiX v3.0 Patch element over the old PatchCreation element. Makes it possible to target patching to only the Fragments you want.